# Image conversion Function using python and open

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Recently I have started learning opencv and python for image processing .I am facing problems with writing a function .

I was given a task as follows:

*Write a function in python to open a color image and convert the image into   grayscale.*

*You are required to write a function color_grayscale(filename,g) which takes two arguments:*

```
  a. filename: a color image (Test color image is in folder “Task1_Practice/test_images”. Pick first image to perform the experiment.)

  b. g: an integer
```

*Output of program should be a grayscale image if g = 1 and a color image otherwise.*

The code i wrote is as follows :

```
import cv2

def color_grayscale(filename,g):

    filename = cv2.imread("a15.jpg")
    " Enter Value of g:"
    if g == 1:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(filename, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img = cv2.imshow("gray",gray)
    else:
        img = cv2.imshow("original",filename)
    return(img)

color_grayscale("a15.jpg",1)
```

The code when run gives no output whatsoever.

Comment: You return `img` but don't do anything with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.imshow` should be followed by `waitKey` function which displays the image for specified milliseconds. Otherwise, it won’t display the image. For example, `waitKey(0)` will display the window infinitely until any keypress (it is suitable for image display). `waitKey(25)` will display a frame for 25 ms, after which display will be automatically closed. (If you put it in a loop to read videos, it will display the video frame-by-frame)

Just add `cv2.waitKey(0)` before you return `img` and then it will display the grayscale image

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, The actual task was to accept value of g then print gray scale image or normal image. When i run the above prg. a gray scale image is displayed.Can u plz suggest me how accept value of g then accordingly display img. also i have to accept "ffilename"from user . How can  do it?